# Jhipster - Angular receive navigation of other users

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, routes, jhipster

I have problem with my Jhipster implementation. When I login as user in a browser and after that login as admin in another browser pages navigation of admin is executed on both admin and user. It doesn't matter that I'm using different browsers and different users.

I don't know from where my problem is coming (Jhipster configuration, Angular or Spring). 
Can someone help with this?

Comment: Does it happen also in production? It could be due to browser-sync which is used only in dev.

Comment: I'll check it in production. I think that you are right. It seems to be browser-sync.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the BrowserSync plugin that is enabled only in development and should never happen when the production profile is active.

You can disable this behaviour by setting the `ghostMode` flag to `false` for the `BrowserSyncPlugin` configuration in your `webpack.dev.js` or `webpack.custom.js`. Like so:

```
new BrowserSyncPlugin({
   https: options.tls,
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 9000,
   ghostMode: false, // <-- this
...
```

More info: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-ghostMode